# Order by and distinct

Tags: python, django

I have the following query:

```
objects = Position.objects.exclude(latitude__isnull=True).exclude(
            longitude__isnull=True).exclude(investor__isnull=True).filter(point__distance_lte = (ref_pnt, D(**distance_from_point) )).distance(ref_pnt)
objects = objects.order_by('investor', 'distance').distinct('investor')
```

I want to order the position objects by distance. How do I do that?

When I do `order_by('investor', 'distance')` it first orders by the investor name, but that's not what I want to do.

How can I have `distinct('investor')` and `order_by('distance')`?

Comment: did you try `order_by('distance').distinct('investor')`?

Comment: that's an error because the order clause has to match the distinct clause it seems.

Comment: ELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("public_position"."startup_id") (ST_dist.

Comment: Django ORM is not expressive enough to get the result you want in one take. You will have to sort in Python or resort to raw SQL (using `extra` or `raw`).

Comment: what version of django?